# Override view templates in a Sinatra app mounted on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sinatra

I have a 3rd-party Sinatra(1.3.3) application which I mount in my Rails(3.2.8) router. But I'd like to override the page templates so it looks in line with the other parts. How can I tell Sinatra to look for the templates in my Rails `app/views` directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not your app, maybe you can use inheritance.

```
class MyApp < ThirdPartyApp

  configure do
    set :views, '/path/to/rails/views' # Override
  end

end
```

**Routes:**

```
mount MyApp.new, at: '/my_app'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Sinatra application define the following:

```
set :views, '/path/to/rails/views'
```

Comment: Thanks, but you didn't read my question carefully. It's not my Sinatra application.